# how to build a URL for a json object consisting of a multiple column primary key?

Tags: json, rest, url

**Step 1:**

If i have a json object

```
{
    "person" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "lastName" : "Hammer",
        "firstName" : "Mike",
        ...
    },
}
```

I can address the object by its name and ID

```
GET http://host/persons/1/
```

**Step 2:**

Now I have a data model containing a primary key consisting of multiple attributes.

for example primary key is (firstName,lastName). There is no single primary key like "id".

```
{
   "person" : {
      "lastName" : "Hammer",
      "firstName" : "Mike",
      ...
   },
}
```

What is the syntax to build a URL for this?

```
GET http://host/persons/???
```

Comment: That depends on how you implement it …

Comment: Thanks. I am primarily interested in interface design (independent of implementation). If there is a golden convention for this case, I would like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the rendering of :

```
GET http://host/persons/1/
```

is based on custom code.

then you could use the following scheme for multi-field keys :

```
GET http://host/persons/field1/field2
```

in the given case:

```
GET http://host/persons/lastName/firstname
```

In general URIs as defined by RFC 3986 (see Section 2: Characters) may contain any of the following characters: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=. Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh)  .

Your could read up on good practices for REST ful  URIs on the web such as : http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/

If you would like to include meta-data such as field-names in the url , you would have to put it in as key=value format for each field in the primary key of a multi-part key separated by a semicolon.

ex:   `GET http://host/persons/lastName=Doe;firstname=John/address/home`

Comment: In case field1 and field2 are just some ids, that would result in /persons/132/342, which does not name the field names. I wonder if something like /persons/lastname/132/firstname/342/ would be better from view of interface design.